# iAd code sketchy

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iad

I have implimented the iAd code, however both on the simulator and on my device it likes to make the iAd disappear after a while, even when the internet connection is fine.  Is there something that I did wrong with my implementation, or is this just expected? Below is both the code, and the Console that shows how often both are being called. Thanks!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    adView.frame = CGRectOffset(adView.frame, 0, 435);   //orginally -50
 adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
 adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    adView.delegate = self;
    self.bannerIsVisible = NO;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");

 if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];
        // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, -25);  //orginally 50
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"bannerViewRecievedError");
 if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];
        // banner is visible and we move it out of the screen, due to connection issue
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, 25);  //orginally -50
        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}

- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"dealloc");
    adView.delegate=nil;
    [adView release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Heres what the console says:

```
2010-12-29 20:04:17.717 app[48943:207] bannerViewRecievedError
2010-12-29 20:04:52.410 app[48943:207] bannerViewRecievedError
2010-12-29 20:05:17.168 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:05:47.166 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:06:16.993 app[48943:207] bannerViewRecievedError
2010-12-29 20:06:46.803 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:07:17.314 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:07:47.140 app[48943:207] bannerViewRecievedError
2010-12-29 20:08:19.899 app[48943:207] bannerViewRecievedError
2010-12-29 20:08:46.978 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:09:17.106 app[48943:207] bannerViewRecievedError
2010-12-29 20:09:46.930 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:10:17.114 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
2010-12-29 20:10:47.609 app[48943:207] bannerViewDidLoadAd
```

Comment: can you help me on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953418/implementation-for-iad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there's no problem here. Apple serves up new simulated ads every so often, and sometimes you'll get hit with an error to test your error-handling capabilities. The error probably means "No Inventory Available", which would make your ad disappear. From the [relevant developer documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html):

> If an error occurs, the banner view
>   calls the delegate’s
>   bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:
>   method. When this happens, your
>   application must hide the banner view.
>   Listing 2-3 shows one way you might
>   implement this. It uses the same
>   property as Listing 2-2 to keep track
>   of whether the banner is visible. If
>   the banner is visible and an error
>   occurs, it moves the banner off the
>   screen.
>
> Even after an error is sent to your
>   delegate, the banner view continues to
>   try to download new advertisements.
>   The combination of these two delegate
>   methods allows you to display the
>   banner only when advertisements are
>   loaded.

Nice job on a good error handling implementation!

Comment: can you help me on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953418/implementation-for-iad

Answer (score 0):

It's designed to do this to ensure that you can deal with iAd errors correctly. It will randomly give you errors as well as good test data.

Comment: can you help me on this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953418/implementation-for-iad